# Use team viewer with different desktop

Tags: windows, windows-8, remote-desktop, desktop, teamviewer

I have a computer with windows 8. Is there a way to access this computer from work with team viewer but using another desktop? 
I want the person at home to still be able to use the computer, watch a movie, anything...

Comment: Please specify, what is the another desktop.

Comment: @Buscar웃 What do you mean? Other windows desktop in the same PC. For example if I had a computer and you would want to do something in my computer remotely and in this time I want to watch a movie in full screen and not be bothered by whatever you are doing remotely...

Comment: I do not understand your question. Just turn off the teamviewer screen on the guest computer than? (minimize it). You do not have to watch it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I can minimize it and watch a movie in full screen but what about the person that is accessing remotely my computer? He will see my movie in full screen and couldn't do anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your conversation, no. If someone is accessing the desktop remotely (via GUI), then it is not possible for one person to watch a movie and the other do what they want. The exception to this is if you are just using the FTP feature.